# Python MD5 : TypeError: object supporting the buffer API required

Tags: python, md5

My code looks like this:

```py
EncryptingKey = hashlib.md5(Random(32000))
```

When I run this code I get this error:

```
TypeError: object supporting the buffer API required
```

Can anyone tell me what to do to the parameter of `haslib.md5()` in order to get it working?

Comment: Please show enough code to replicate your problem

Comment: `hashlib.md5()` expects a binary string as its first parameter. You can always check that with `help(hashlib.md5)`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:`hashlib.md5(Random(32000).to_bytes(2, byteorder='big' ))`
It expects a byte inpute